# Как перебирать массив чтобы при наличии переданного элемента запускалась функция , иначе запускалась другая функция?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть массив элементов с названием игр. Он отображается на странице у каждой игры есть кнопка добавление в закладки. При нажатие на кнопку игра добавляется в закладку и закладка светится черным при повторном удаляется из закладки.

```
 <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark"  onClick={e => this.updateMarker("newItem", item)}>
<FaStar />
    </button>

 updateMarker(key, value) {
    this.state.newItem = value
    // update react state
    this.setState({ [key]: value });

    // update localStorage
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);



   if(this.state.list.length === 0){
        this.addMarker()
    }else{
        this.state.list.forEach((item) => {
            if(value === item.value){
                console.log('повтор  удалять', item.value,  value)
                this.deleteMarker(value)
            }else {
                console.log('запись', item.value, '===', value)
                this.addMarker()
            }
        })
    }
}

addMarker = () => {
    // create a new item
    const newItem = {
        id: 1 + Math.random(),
        value: this.state.newItem.slice()
    };

    // copy current list of items
    const list = [...this.state.list];

    // add the new item to the list
    list.push(newItem);

    // update state with new list, reset the new item input
    this.setState({
        list,
        newItem: ""
    });

    // update localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
    localStorage.setItem("newItem", "");

    console.log('add',localStorage)
}



deleteMarker(value) {
    // copy current list of items
    const list = [...this.state.list];
    // filter out the item being deleted
    const updatedList = list.filter(item => item.value !== value);

    this.setState({ list: updatedList });

    // update localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(updatedList));
    console.log('delete',localStorage)
}
```

Использовал функцию .forEach c условием есть есть такая игра в массиве, то удали иначе добавь. Но проблема в этом способе что он проверяет все элементы то есть 100 игр и он 99 раз вызовет запись и 1 раз вызовет удаление.
Есть ли какой то другой метод перебора, или как вызвать функцию когда есть хотя бы один true на удаление, если нет то вызвать запись ?

Comment: Что-то в этом духе? `if (!this.state.list.some(item => {if (value === item.value) { this.deleteMarker(value); return true } return false;})) this.addMarker()`

Comment: @Yaant Да спасибо) я плох с массивами надо учить все встроенные функции.